# How to remove shadows from this board image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the following image and I am trying to find a way to remove the shadows of all green and red pieces and the right black wall. I have tried converting the image to HSV and playing with masks, but I got nowhere. Any help or advice on how to proceed is appreciated as I have never worked with opencv before.

[image]

And by applying mask as seen on the code below, I get a slightly..better version but I have no idea how to proceed:

```
lower = (50, 50, 50)
upper = (255, 255, 255)

red_mask = cv2.inRange(cropped, lower, upper)
cropped[red_mask != 0] = [255, 255, 255]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your image with white background (not gray) i have found this shadow mask

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


im = cv2.imread('images/lego-shadow.png')

cvt=67 #or 41
dc=112

if dc<1:
    dc = 0

while True:
    try:

        img = cv2.cvtColor(im,cvt)
        lower = (80, 80, 80)
        upper = (80+dc, 80+dc,80+dc)

        mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

        cv2.imshow('mask',cv2.resize(mask,(640,480)))

    except:
        pass

    k=cv2.waitKey(33) & 0xFF
    if k==ord('1'):
        cvt-=1
        print(cvt)
    if k==ord('2'):
        cvt+=1
        print(cvt)
    if k==ord('3'):
        dc-=1
        print("dc ",dc,lower,upper)
    if k==ord('4'):
        dc+=1
        print("dc ",dc,lower,upper)

    if k==ord('c'):break
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQSXN.png

**What the code do**

```
cv2.cvtColor(image ,  here the number that indendify conversion code )
```

Here there are all the color conversions code numbers used by cvtColor:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html

keyboard Keys 1,2 (for cvt code)  and  3,4 (for delta color dc) are used  to increment or decrement their values.

Playing with these keys you can found many mask combinations quickly.

So , enjoy !

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great! Would you mind telling me quickly what is the code doing exactly as I'm having a hard time understanding it?